# css not working on mobile device, cropped layout

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

I have made a webpage which is working on any browser but not on mobile devices. The webpages may seems like very unprofessional but it is for testing. I think maybe the problem seems to be in the viewport settings in css.

Can someone help me out? The link is:
http://www.moworkflow.nl/test/responsiveapp.html

Comment: whats not working in mobile devices?

Comment: Can you add screenshot of mobile device trying to view your website, how bad does it look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From quick look at your website, it seems you are using vw and vh units of measurement. Its cool that you are following new trends but that 'technology' is partly supported especially on phones. If you are testing your website on some smartphones like android <3.4, everything will be broken because they doesn't support vh or vw at all. I am not sure about other devices.

Fix for your problem is to use px,% or some other widely supported unit.

EDIT:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

I was right, there is just partly support for this units. Check this site from time to time. :)

Comment: Really thanks for your comment, I am going to look for another way to solve my problem. I hope the percentage will work but i have made a quick experiment and by simply changing width: 100vw to width: 100% doesn't solve it.

Comment: I fixed a lot of my bugs with the percentage measurement. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. We are here to help.